# xsl select node based on number value

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xslt

I have an xml document that I am trying to style with xsl. The problem is depending on the value I need to pull from a certain node, but in xsl I do not know how to distinguish between the two following nodes:

XML:

```
<a number=1>
<car>1</car>
</a>

<a number=2>
<dog>1</dog>
</a>

<I_want_to_display>
<number>2</number>
</I_want_to_display>
```

XSL:

```
 <xsl:for-eachselect="I_want_to_display">
      <xsl:if test="number==2">
      ....display everything in <a number=2>
      </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Your input is not even XML. Please fix it.

Comment: You should add an example of exactly what you're expecting for output.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that is the simplest and shortest so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what output you're looking for, but here's a guess.

This well-formed XML input:

```
<xml>
  <a number="1">
    <car>1</car>
  </a>

  <a number="2">
    <dog>1</dog>
  </a>

  <I_want_to_display>
    <number>2</number>
  </I_want_to_display>
</xml>
```

with this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="I_want_to_display">
    <xsl:variable name="vNbr" select="number/text()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//*[normalize-space(@number) = $vNbr]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this output:

```
<a number="2">
   <dog>1</dog>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath one-liner**:

```
/*/*[@number = /*/I_want_to_display/number]
```

**The complete XSLT code (9 lines)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[@number = /*/I_want_to_display/number]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (as no well-formed XML document was provided!):

```
<t>
    <a number="1">
        <car>1</car>
    </a>
    <a number="2">
        <dog>1</dog>
    </a>
    <I_want_to_display>
        <number>2</number>
    </I_want_to_display>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a number="2">
   <dog>1</dog>
</a>
```

**Explanation**: The XPath operator `=` when applied on two node-sets is `true()` for every pair of nodes (one from the first node-set and the second from the second node-set), that have the same string value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="I_want_to_display">
  <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::a[@number = current()/number]/node()>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can gather the `a` nodes with a key:

```
<xsl:key name="ka" match="a" use="@number"/>
```

and use the key to refer them later iside the required template, like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="I_want_to_display">
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('ka',normalize-space(number))"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```